# ScrollView Constraint problem threw storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, scrollview

So I maybe successfully created a scroll view following a tutorial but something is terribly wrong. So I'm trying to create a scroll view with a table view inside and some buttons and labels and everything works fine but as soon as I add a single constraint it all goes just white with no explanation. I would assume content view is messing things up but I'm not sure, thx in advance!

So following some other people problems I tried filling constraints programmatically and doing views and subviews programmatically aswell, keep in mind tho that rest of constraints I did on storyboard. Btw I have tried equal width and height on newView --> scroll view and nothing seems to change.

my view hierarchy looks like this
myViewController -> View -> scrollView -> newView

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.addSubview(newView)

        newView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        newView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        newView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        newView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        //tableView1.dataSource = self
        //tableView1.delegate = self
        //tableView1.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var newView: UIView!

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 1950)

    }
}
```

Sorry, if question is layout pretty badly - I'm not that pro!

Comment: Why you use a tableview inside a scrollview ? can't you use tableview only ?

Comment: thought it might lag out the system and the fact that I don't know how to place a table view inside a table view, cuz need like 6 separate table views

Comment: as i feel you can use 1 table with and use tableview section as subtable view in that way you can create the view you want.